# will creating a desktop application in Node js put my code in danger of being public?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, desktop-application

I am planning on creating a desktop version of my web application. But I'm afraid the server code can also be viewed by the end user. Because on the desktop everything is `JavaScript`, unlike .exe files. I'm using `APP.js`.

Edit: Is there anyway we can hide our code?

Comment: why not?, will be the question

Comment: Is the server code also run on the client machine? Or do you only have a desktop client that interacts with your node.js server like a browser client?

Comment: Take a look into this: https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón,@xander.  Most of the contents in the app is dynamic. I'm getting the data from server manipulating here using any template engine. so that they can guess the table structure and table names also.

Comment: no matter, i can see problem, take care with security

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón is there anyway we can hide our code?

Comment: @SarathKumar, its called obfuscation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

giving your executable to people means they will be able to get your original logic and understand exactly how your code works, .exe files are not safe from this either as they are open to reverse engineering.

I suggest looking into binary and code obfuscation.

Comment: Yes that is possible. Not by everyone. But Javascript is more easier crack.

Comment: @SarathKumar, easier to crack is relative, even a dll can be decompiled to a degree readable by humans (e.g. java bytecodes, .net ILs). whatever you do, if the source is at the end user, it will be crackable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a node packager like https://github.com/zeit/pkg It will pack and make it ready to distribute on different platform without any js inside.

Answer (score 1):

With NW.js you can compile your JS file to bytecode/machine code without distributing your JS file. See http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/

Answer (score 0):

I have used zeit/pkg, to package nodejs application. It hides all the source code and makes a single executable for different platforms.

Please add the below code to work with pkg in Nodejs App:

**package.json**

```
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "npm start"
 },
"bin" : "$DIR\node_modules\npm\cli.js"
```

Then run command **pkg .**

***Note* :**

1)  You can also directly package app.js (in case if you dont have any other assets to add in pkg) by command :

```
pkg app.js
```

2) It will create executables in your current working directory.

3) You can also give entrypoint in "bin" :

Example :

**package.json**

```
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "npm start"
 },
"bin" : "./bin/my-bin.js"
```

**bin/my-bin.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var join = require('path').join
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

 args.unshift(__dirname + '/../'); 

childProcess.exec('npm start', (err, stdout) => {
if (err) console.log(err);
console.log(stdout);
})
```

Then, in current working directory,

run

```
pkg .
```